# Awarding helpful people in chat

Tags: discussion, reputation, chat

The fact that SO is oriented around questions is a given, but some problems are just not fit to be questions for a variety of reasons:

1. They may be too localized (system specific etc)
2. The may be unbelievably silly/easy
3. The OP may not know exactly where the problem is and may be in the process of closing in to it.
4. They may require additional information that the OP does not know he has to post in order to get an answer at the time he posts.
5. They may be extremely quick (syntax related etc)

Still (I personally, and I feel many users like me) need answers on those types of questions too.

There are people in chat that are extremely helpful, and I feel they should be somehow rewarded for that.

Also, people must be motivated to form their questions in a Q&A form.

So what I'd really like to see is the asker to reward the answerer with one or two of his own reputation points.

That way askers are not going there unless they have no other way, and we can give something  more than just a thank you to the people in chat that helped us.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to take out a bounty on another question that the chat user has already answered and reward it them via the existing method.  It's a lot more than just a few rep points, but if someone has really gone out of their way to help you, it's likely worth it.

I can't see an elaborate system being built on top of chat for rewarding answers given there without a lot of unnecessary changes to the system and possibilities for misuse/abuse.

Comment: A simple system can just give me the opportunity to reward the person that helped me with one of my reputation points. It would be perfect with a time delay of a day or two, so no one is obliged to do it, but you can express your gratitude.

Comment: What's to stop you and I from trading rep back and forth that way in chat?  What infrastructure would be able to gauge whether a question was in fact answered and rep can be rewarded?

Comment: Since it would be my own hard won reputation, I wouldn't really want to give it away unless I got helped. What type of misuse am I missing?

Comment: Think of it as "horse trading" for privileges on the site.  One user could give another user the right to vote, or downvote, etc. outside of the normal hierarchy.

Comment: (a couple of points here and there, and everything adds up)

Comment: What I now do is just find a question of the person that helped me and upvote it. I just feel there should be a more 'official' way to do it

Comment: If you can propose a method by which I can't just wake up and say, I'm going to give AnPel 2 rep because I like his avatar or something that doesn't overly complicate the existing chat UI, I'd say sure, I just don't think it's possible.

Comment: fair enough. I think the fact that the rep will be reduced from you will be enough and you don't. Chances are you know more. Let it be noted that if there could be a viable way to do so, I'd like it as a user.